# Data defined labeling of coordinates

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling

Another labelling question. I have shape-points which are shown as circles in QGIS. The bigger the data, the bigger the circle. Now i want to label the points with the data defined properties, so that the label of each point is directly shown on top of the circle. How to do that? I have to move the y-coordinate...

Basically like this?

CASE

WHEN "ID"= 10 THEN y-coordinate= +5

WHEN "ID"= 20 THEN y-coordinate= +10

and so on...

ELSE y-coordinate should stay normal

END

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:
[image: rule-based placement]
and use the rule:

```
CASE 
WHEN "ID"= 10 THEN '0,-5'
WHEN "ID"= 20 THEN '0,-10'
[...]
ELSE '0,0'
END
```

Answer (score 5):

You can label around the point style under label 'Placement'. Check 'Cartographic' and set 'Distance offset from' to 'From symbol bounds'.  You can then apply an offset distance and all your labels will be uniform from the point style.

To position directly above the point use the data defined override on the 'Position priority' to `'T'`.  Hover over the override button to get the other options for label placement.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, you can indeed do that for labelling point symbols. Best answer!